# Generate the Dominant Colors for an RGB image with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, tvos, quantization, tvml, tvjs

**A Note For Readers: This is a long question, but it needs a background to understand the question asked.**

The [color quantization technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_quantization) is commonly used to get the *dominant colors* of an image.
One of the well-known libraries that do color quantization is [Leptonica](http://www.leptonica.com/) through the [Modified Median Cut Quantization (MMCQ) and octree quantization (OQ)](http://www.leptonica.com/color-quantization.html)
Github's [Color-thief](https://github.com/lokesh/color-thief) by @lokesh is a very simple implementation in JavaScript of the MMCQ algorithm:

```
var colorThief = new ColorThief();
colorThief.getColor(sourceImage);
```

Technically, the image on a `<img/>` HTML element is backed on a `<canvas/>` element:

```
var CanvasImage = function (image) {
    this.canvas  = document.createElement('canvas');
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

    document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);

    this.width  = this.canvas.width  = image.width;
    this.height = this.canvas.height = image.height;

    this.context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);
};
```

And that is the problem with `TVML`, as we will see later on.

Another implementation I recently came to know was linked on this article [Using imagemagick, awk and kmeans to find dominant colors in images](http://javier.io/blog/en/2015/09/30/using-imagemagick-and-kmeans-to-find-dominant-colors-in-images.html) that links to [Using python to generate awesome linux desktop themes](http://charlesleifer.com/blog/using-python-to-generate-awesome-linux-desktop-themes/). 
The author posted an article about [Using python and k-means to find the dominant colors in images](http://charlesleifer.com/blog/using-python-and-k-means-to-find-the-dominant-colors-in-images/) that was used there (sorry for all those links, but I'm following back my History...).

The author was super productive, and added a JavaScript version too that I'm posting here: [Using JavaScript and k-means to find the dominant colors in images](https://gist.github.com/loretoparisi/c147ca437ab9d5e163b7)

In this case, we are generating the dominant colors of an image, not using the MMCQ (or OQ) algorithm, but K-Means.
The problem is that the image must be a  as well:

```
<canvas id="canvas" style="display: none;" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

and then

```
function analyze(img_elem) {
        var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d')
          , img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
          var results = document.getElementById('results');
          results.innerHTML = 'Waiting...';
          var colors = process_image(img, ctx)
            , p1 = document.getElementById('c1')
            , p2 = document.getElementById('c2')
            , p3 = document.getElementById('c3');
          p1.style.backgroundColor = colors[0];
          p2.style.backgroundColor = colors[1];
          p3.style.backgroundColor = colors[2];
          results.innerHTML = 'Done';
        }
        img.src = img_elem.src;
      }
```

This is because the Canvas has a getContext() method, that expose 2D image drawing APIs - see [An introduction to the Canvas 2D API](http://html5doctor.com/an-introduction-to-the-canvas-2d-api/)

This context ctx is passed to the image processing function

```
  function process_image(img, ctx) {
    var points = [];
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 200, 200);
    data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 200, 200).data;
    for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l;  i += 4) {
      var r = data[i]
        , g = data[i+1]
        , b = data[i+2];
      points.push([r, g, b]);
    }
    var results = kmeans(points, 3, 1)
     , hex = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      hex.push(rgbToHex(results[i][0]));
    }
    return hex;
  }
```

So you can draw an image on the Canvas through the Context and get image data:

```
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 200, 200);
data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 200, 200).data;
```

Another nice solution is in CoffeeScript, [ColorTunes](https://github.com/dannvix/ColorTunes), but this is using a  as well:

```
ColorTunes.getColorMap = function(canvas, sx, sy, w, h, nc) {
    var index, indexBase, pdata, pixels, x, y, _i, _j, _ref, _ref1;
    if (nc == null) {
      nc = 8;
    }
    pdata = canvas.getContext("2d").getImageData(sx, sy, w, h).data;
    pixels = [];
    for (y = _i = sy, _ref = sy + h; _i < _ref; y = _i += 1) {
      indexBase = y * w * 4;
      for (x = _j = sx, _ref1 = sx + w; _j < _ref1; x = _j += 1) {
        index = indexBase + (x * 4);
        pixels.push([pdata[index], pdata[index + 1], pdata[index + 2]]);
      }
    }
    return (new MMCQ).quantize(pixels, nc);
  };
```

But, wait, we have no `<canvas/>` element in `TVML`!

Of course, there are native solutions like Objective-C [ColorCube](https://github.com/pixelogik/ColorCube), [DominantColor](https://github.com/indragiek/DominantColor) - this is using K-means

and the very nice and reusable [ColorArt](https://github.com/panicinc/ColorArt) by @AaronBrethorst from CocoaControls.

Despite the fact that this could be used in a TVML application through a native to JavaScriptCore bridge - see [How to bridge TVML/JavaScriptCore to UIKit/Objective-C (Swift)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33081565/tvos-tvml-and-objective-c-swift-putting-all-together)

my aim is to make this work completely in `TVJS` and `TVML`.

The simplest MMCQ JavaScript implementation does not need a Canvas: see [Basic Javascript port of the MMCQ (modified median cut quantization)](https://gist.github.com/loretoparisi/fe6e5cf889bb2c8f2099) by [Nick Rabinowitz](https://gist.github.com/nrabinowitz), but needs the RGB array of the image:

```
var cmap = MMCQ.quantize(pixelArray, colorCount);
```

that is taken from the HTML `<canvas/>` and that is the reason for it!

```
function createPalette(sourceImage, colorCount) {

    // Create custom CanvasImage object
    var image = new CanvasImage(sourceImage),
        imageData = image.getImageData(),
        pixels = imageData.data,
        pixelCount = image.getPixelCount();

    // Store the RGB values in an array format suitable for quantize function
    var pixelArray = [];
    for (var i = 0, offset, r, g, b, a; i < pixelCount; i++) {
        offset = i * 4;
        r = pixels[offset + 0];
        g = pixels[offset + 1];
        b = pixels[offset + 2];
        a = pixels[offset + 3];
        // If pixel is mostly opaque and not white
        if (a >= 125) {
            if (!(r > 250 && g > 250 && b > 250)) {
                pixelArray.push([r, g, b]);
            }
        }
    }

    // Send array to quantize function which clusters values
    // using median cut algorithm

    var cmap = MMCQ.quantize(pixelArray, colorCount);
    var palette = cmap.palette();

    // Clean up
    image.removeCanvas();

    return palette;
}
```

**[QUESTION]**
How to generate the dominant colors of a RGB image without using the HTML5 `<canvas/>`, but in pure JavaScript from an image's `ByteArray` fetched with `XMLHttpRequest`?

**[UPDATE]**
I have posted this question to [Color-Thief](https://github.com/lokesh/color-thief/issues/86) github repo, adapting the RGB array calculations to the latest codebase.
The solution I have tried was this

```
ColorThief.prototype.getPaletteNoCanvas = function(sourceImageURL, colorCount, quality, done) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', sourceImageURL, true);
  xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
  xhr.onload = function(e) {
    if (this.status == 200) {

      var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(this.response);
      var i = uInt8Array.length;
      var biStr = new Array(i);
      while (i--)
      { biStr[i] = String.fromCharCode(uInt8Array[i]);
      }

      if (typeof colorCount === 'undefined') {
          colorCount = 10;
      }
      if (typeof quality === 'undefined' || quality < 1) {
          quality = 10;
      }

      var pixels     = uInt8Array;
      var pixelCount = 152 * 152 * 4 // this should be width*height*4

      // Store the RGB values in an array format suitable for quantize function
      var pixelArray = [];
      for (var i = 0, offset, r, g, b, a; i < pixelCount; i = i + quality) {
          offset = i * 4;
          r = pixels[offset + 0];
          g = pixels[offset + 1];
          b = pixels[offset + 2];
          a = pixels[offset + 3];
          // If pixel is mostly opaque and not white
          if (a >= 125) {
              if (!(r > 250 && g > 250 && b > 250)) {
                  pixelArray.push([r, g, b]);
              }
          }
      }

      // Send array to quantize function which clusters values
      // using median cut algorithm
      var cmap    = MMCQ.quantize(pixelArray, colorCount);
      var palette = cmap? cmap.palette() : null;
      done.apply(this,[ palette ])

    } // 200
  };
  xhr.send();
}
```

but it does not gives back the right RGB colors array.

**[UPDATE]**
Thanks to all the suggestions I got it working. Now a full example is available on [Github](https://github.com/loretoparisi/dominant-colors-xmlhttprequest-example),

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canvas element is being used as a convenient way to decode the image into an RGBA array. You can also use pure JavaScript libraries to do the image decoding.

[jpgjs](https://github.com/notmasteryet/jpgjs) is a JPEG decoder and [pngjs](https://github.com/arian/pngjs) is a PNG decoder. It looks like the JPEG decoder will work with TVJS as is. The PNG decoder, however, looks like it's made to work in a Node or web browser environment, so you might have to tweak that one a bit.

Comment: Well, I have in fact opened an issue on jpgjs: https://github.com/notmasteryet/jpgjs/issues/40. it partially works, since the result it's not exactly the same achieved with RGB byte array from Canvas (Still investigating why...)

Comment: I have update the ```jpg.js``` issue with more info and posted a online demo here: http://www.parisilabs.com/colors2/ showing the results.

Comment: It looks like you pretty much have it, just some minor variation. I noticed in the canvas version of your code (process_image) you scale the image down before reading the bytes out `ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 200, 200)`. However, I don't see the same scaling code in the example in the comment right above this one. Perhaps that explains the difference?

Comment: I have checked the code, and finally realized that I was calling with the Canvas ```MMCQ.quantize(pixelArray, 5)``` while with jpg.js ```MMCQ.quantize(pixelArray, 8)``` where the integer is ```var cmap = MMCQ.quantize(myPixels, maxColors);```. Thank you for your help, it seems now we have ```Leptonica``` MMCQ running via ```XHttpRequest```! only!  - check it out now here http://www.parisilabs.com/colors2/