# How to push TVML template from UIKit app?

Tags: tvos, tvml

I am writing a native tvOS app, but would like to use one of the templates provided by Apple as well. I have found posts explaining how to push UIKit views onto a TVML app, but not the other way around.

Maybe it's really simple if you're across Javascript, but I'm not, unfortunately.

Can someone explain how to go about this?

Comment: I was personally looking for it as well. Seems multiple people asked for it on their developer forums but not a single reply. I don't think it is possible at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered this question in detail here:

[Can I mix UIKit and TVMLKit within one app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305352/can-i-mix-uikit-and-tvmlkit-within-one-app/33531442#33531442)

The trick is to use a **TVApplicationController** object in your application

```
var appController: TVApplicationController?
```

TVApplicationController objects have a navigationController associated with them.  They also have a JavaScript context associated with them, which is what controls the TVML Templates.

Once you can communicate between Javascript and UIKit as I've demonstrated in my answer above, you'll be able to utilize the [NavigationDocument](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/TVMLJS/Reference/TVJSNavigationDocument_Ref/index.html) in TVJS.  Push a template onto the navigationDocument and, voila, it will appear on the TV.