# How can I embed Facebook login in a TVML app?

Tags: xcode, facebook, swift, tvml

If I understand correctly [Facebook SDK for tvOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tvos) contains instructions of how to embed login if the app is native.

How can one embed Facebook login in a TVML app?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to use the tvOS Facebook SDK if you are only coding in javascript and TVML.  The good news is that you can mix UIKit with TVML and javascript with swift/objective-c.

Check out my answer here for an explanation on how to do that:

[Can I Mix UIKit and TVML Within One App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305352/can-i-mix-uikit-and-tvmlkit-within-one-app/33531442#33531442)

Using this approach, you'll be able to utilize the Facebook SDK and still use TVML Templates.

UPDATE: You can also just use Facebook's javascript API if you would like to keep your app soley TVML/TVJS https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript

UPDATE2: From Chris the commenter: "We just released v4.10 of the FB SDK for tvOS with TVML extensions to make this much easier: check out [developers.facebook.com/docs/tvos/tvml](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tvos/tvml)"

Comment: Thank you, I have already implemented that. There seems to be a way, as stated [here](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/permalink/976623965714451/?comment_id=990274054349442&notif_t=group_comment_reply)

Comment: We just released v4.10 of the FB SDK for tvOS with TVML extensions to make this much easier: check out https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tvos/tvml