# Does the keyboard for a UITextField have to take up the whole screen?

Tags: swift, tvos, uikeyboard

*It seems that the keyboard doesn't have to take up the whole screen, check UPDATE in the Question section of my post. Thanks.*

### Description

> Use UITextField to place a full-screen keyboard on the screen.

[reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/CreatingaGreatTextInputExperience.html)

I've set up a `UISplitViewController` and I would like the `RootViewController` (aka `MasterViewController`) to have the `UITextField` with the Keyboard showing. Then I would like results of the search on the right (in the "ResultViewController" (UIViewController).

The idea is when the user types, results are proposed.

### What I've tried:

I first added a `UITextField` to my `RootViewController` via the `storyboard` but that took up the whole screen when I activated the keyboard via `textField.becomeFirstResponder()`.

I figured if I use a `UIAlertController` I'd get by this issue, but the keyboard still takes up the whole screen.

```
class RootViewController: UIViewController {

 override func viewDidLoad() {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Search", message: "Search for something!.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({(textField: UITextField!) in
        textField.placeholder = "Search"
    })
    self.addChildViewController(alertController)
    alertController.view.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(alertController.view)
 }
}
```

### Question:

When using a `UISplitViewController` how can I get the keyboard to only stay in it's `RootViewController` and not take up the whole screen?

**UPDATE:** It appears this has been implemented in the Netflix app on the new apple tv. The keyboard is on the top and takes up the whole width. The bottom is divided into two sections. On the left, proposed word results and on the right a collection view of video covers of possible videos. Everything is updated as the user types.

<s>If this is considered bad design for Apple TV, then feel free to point out why.</s>

### Screen shot:

This is what I currently get. The text box opens a keyboard that takes up the whole screen.

[image]

Comment: i would recommend not to implement such design. Even more you can be rejected by Apple because of avoiding HIG (Human interface guidelines)

Comment: @ale_stro Why would this be rejected on tvOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Introduction:

I was finally able to implement this without having to use `TVML templates`. The final solution looks something like this:

[image: text keyboard and results on one view]

The general idea is to create a `UICollectionViewController` with a `UICollectionViewCell`. Then to programmatically add a keyboard and add it to your `TabViewController` via your `AppDelegate`.

---

### How to implement this search view with results:

**Step 1: Storyboard and Controller creation**

Open your storyboard and create a `UICollectionViewController` (with a custom class "`SearchResultViewController`") that **is not** attached to your `TabViewController`.

Within it create a your `UICollectionViewCell` with whatever `labels` and `images` you want. `UICollectionViewCell` should have a custom class called "`VideoSearchCell`".

*Your SearchViewController should have nothing else inside.*

**Step 2: Adding `SearchViewController` to `TabViewController` and implementing keyboard via `AppDelegate` programmatically**

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    override init() {

    }
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        if let tabController = window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
            tabController.viewControllers?.append(configueSearchController())
        }

        return true
    }

    //... standard code in-between

    func configueSearchController() -> UIViewController {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        guard let searchResultController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(SearchResultViewController.storyboardIdentifier) as? SearchResultViewController else {
            fatalError("Unable to instatiate a SearchResultViewController from the storyboard.")
        }

        /*
         Create a UISearchController, passing the `searchResultsController` to
         use to display search results.
         */
        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsController)
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = searchResultsController
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = NSLocalizedString("Enter keyword (e.g. Gastric Bypass)", comment: "")

        // Contain the `UISearchController` in a `UISearchContainerViewController`.
        let searchContainer = UISearchContainerViewController(searchController: searchController)
        searchContainer.title = NSLocalizedString("Search", comment: "")

        // Finally contain the `UISearchContainerViewController` in a `UINavigationController`.
        let searchNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: searchContainer)
        return searchNavigationController

    }

}
```

Once you've added the basic skeleton of your SearchResultViewController you should be able to see the keyboard on the top of the Search view when you run your project.

**Step 3: Handling text input and updating results**

You'll notice that in my `filterString` I use a class called ScoreVideo and a StringSearchService. These are just classes I use to filter my Video list (aka: self.vms.videos).

So in the end, just take the `filterString`, create a new *filtered list* and reload your collection view.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class SearchResultViewController: UICollectionViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {


    //private let cellComposer = DataItemCellComposer()
    private var vms: VideoManagerService!

    private var filteredVideos = [ScoreVideo]()
    static let storyboardIdentifier = "SearchResultViewController"

    var filterString = "" {
        didSet {
            // Return if the filter string hasn't changed.
            guard filterString != oldValue else { return }
                // Apply the filter or show all items if the filter string is empty.
                if self.filterString.isEmpty {
                    self.filteredVideos = StringSearchService.start(self.filterString, videos: self.vms.videos)
                }
                else {
                    self.filteredVideos = StringSearchService.start(self.filterString, videos: self.vms.videos)
                }
           self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        self.vms = appDelegate.getVideoManagerService()

    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("count..\(filteredVideos.count)")
        return filteredVideos.count
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        // Dequeue a cell from the collection view.
        return collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(VideoSearchCell.reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDelegate

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        guard let cell = cell as? VideoSearchCell else { fatalError("Expected to display a `VideoSearchCell`.") }
        let item = filteredVideos[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCell(item.video)

    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    // MARK: UISearchResultsUpdating

    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        print("updating... \(searchController.searchBar.text)")
        filterString = searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercaseString ?? ""
    }
}
```

---

If something is unclear, feel free to ask some questions. I most likely forgot something. Thanks.

Answer inspired from [apple sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/samplecode/UICatalogFortvOS/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: Do you have any sample project . if yes , please share it

Answer (score 6):

Presenting a keyboard only on a portion of the screen is not possible with the built-in SDK methods.

A `UIKeyboard` is presented on the application's window, not on any of its subviews.  To accomplish your desired behavior, use reflection to get a reference to the `UIKeyboard` object on your application's `UIWindow` (by iterating through the window's subviews), and change its frame to match the width of your `RootViewController`.

To get started, you can look at the private UIKeyboard.h tvOS header [here](https://github.com/neonichu/tvOS-headers/blob/master/UIKit/UIKeyboard.h).  I should note that Apple may have code in place to disable resizing of the keyboard (like in `willMoveToWindow:` or `didMoveToWindow` for example).  This is undefined behavior and your milage will vary, if it even works at all.

You have deleted your comment on my answer about the Netflix app, but as shirefriendship says in their answer, Netflix probably uses a TVML template.  You could go that route and build a hybrid tvOS/TVML app.  Additionally, you could also manually build a keyboard yourself with a `UICollectionView` in your `RootViewController`.

Answer (score 4):

Netflix is using TVML Templates to implement their search instead of UIKit.  You can accomplish the same aesthetic as Netflix using the [searchTemplate](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/ATV_Template_Guide/SearchTemplate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015064-CH33-SW1).  You can learn to mix TVML and UIKit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305352/can-i-mix-uikit-and-tvmlkit-within-one-app/33531442#33531442).  Unfortunately the searchTemplate is not customizable enough to conform to your desired layout.  There is currently no way to implement your specific layout for the Apple TV.